# Return according to asynchronous result in Javascript event

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>   

$("a").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("/api",resp =>{
        if(resp.status===0){
            // keep the event propagation
        }else{
            // stop the event propagation
        }
    });
});
```

Given the above example, once user click the link, an ajax call will send to the server, once the responded content is valid, then we should keep the event propagation just like nothing happened, once invalid, then we stop the event propagation which means we should stop the browser jumping to `Google`.

Generally we use the following for synchronous operation:

```
$("a").click(function{{
    if(SyncOperation(xxx)){
        //do nothing
    }else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

I am not sure how to implement that for an asynchronous operation like an ajax call.

Any suggestion?

Comment: you can't effect event propagation asyncrhonously

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)